# PHP remainder is not showing expected output

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate remainder in PHP

**My simple code**

```
echo 0.7%5.1;
```

Output is: 0

Also tried

```
echo  bcmod('0.7', '5.1');
```

But, neither of them are giving the result I expected.

Expected output:  0.7

Comment: It looks like a bug in `bcmod` to me (Forget about using just `%` because that's strictly the integer mod operation). If you use `fmod` it [works](https://3v4l.org/WBXBg). Also seems to work if you use the (barely documented) 3rd parameter of `bcmod`

Answer (score 0):

**Try Like This**

```
<?php
$__dividend = 0.7;
$__divisor = 5.1;

$__remainder = fmod($__dividend, $__divisor);

echo $__remainder;
?>
```